# Garbage Keyboard Information in SDL 2.0

Tags: c++, input, keyboard, sdl

I have the following code to test SDL keyboard input on version 2.0:

```
while (SDL_PollEvent(&evnt))
        {
            if (evnt.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
            {
                board = evnt.key;
                key = board.keysym.sym;

                switch (key)
                {
                    case SDLK_a:
                        printf("a key!\n");
                        break;

                    case SDLK_d:
                        printf("d key!\n");
                        break;

                    default:
                        printf("Code: 0x%X\n", board.keysym.scancode);
                        printf("Name: %s\n", SDL_GetKeyName(key));
                        printf("Hex:  0x%02X\n", key);
                        printf("Uni:  %c\n\n", (char)board.keysym.unicode);
                }
            } else if (evnt.type == SDL_QUIT)
                running = false;
        }
```

However, following is the output for the sequence 'qwerty':

```
Code: 0x460001
Name: ¶
Hex:  0x14
Uni:

Code: 0x460001
Name: →
Hex:  0x1A
Uni:

Code: 0x460001
Name: Backspace
Hex:  0x08
Uni:

Code: 0x460001
Name: §
Hex:  0x15
Uni:

Code: 0x460001
Name: ↨
Hex:  0x17
Uni:

Code: 0x460001
Name: ∟
Hex:  0x1C
Uni:
```

Am I just doing something stupid?

Also, this is not an ideal method for my program. I would prefer to do
if (ispressed['k'])
{ }
etc...

Is there an ability to do this form of input processing in SDL or will I need to write my own class to manage it?

Comment: After running circles and beating my head on the keyboard for long enough, I ended up checking out the code and building sdl myself. The version I built works as expected. Go figure.

Comment: Where were you getting your binaries from anyway?  I'm not seeing any 2.0 binaries on the [main SDL page](http://www.libsdl.org/hg.php).

Comment: A gentlemen had posted in the forums that he had up to date builds on his website. I do not recall the name at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

The switch statement basically is just an if statement.

If you really want to do it your way, it would look like

```
if (event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
        {
            board = evnt.key;
            key = board.keysym.sym;

            if(key==SDLK_a)
            {
                //do stuff here
            }
```

If you want it to look exactly like what you said above, you would need to define a MAP of bools, called isPressed, and whenever you get a key event, pass it to a helper that would set the values in the map based on the key pressed. I'll tell you now - get used to the way SDL 'wants' you to do this. When you are more comfortable with it you'll realize it makes more sense.

As for the bug you are experiencing - I'm not too sure about part of it, but try putting SDL_EnableUNICODE(); in your init. Then test on the same input and report back - I expect that to at least fix your unicode problem.